# how to load vb.net variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I'm trying to add google maps to my website, but instead of fixing a latitude and longitude for the location, I would like to be able to load the values from database. How do I get a variable from vb.net and pass it to javascript? I've tried:

```
<% Response.Write("<script>
    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(1.123456, 1.123456);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'KH Automotive Location'
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>")%>
```

and

```
new google.maps.LatLng(<%=latitude%>, <%=longitude%>);
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, when I need to make absolutely sure (like with translated/localized strings) that the content comes across, I'll write it out to a hidden DIV somewhere on the page (or a hidden INPUT).

`<div style='display:none' id='my_data'>stuffstuffstuff</div>`

Then I just read the contents of the DIV (or INPUT, whatever I used).    Slap a "runat=server" in it, and be able to write to it from your code-behind.

Comment: Hey, do you mean to do a <div id='data'><%=latitude%></div> then var latitude = document.getElementById('data').getAttribute('value'); ?

Comment: Sort of.   If you add runat=server to the DIV element, it's now exposed in your code-behind, so that you can acccess it and set the data via the .InnerHtml property.     You *could* write it inline, like you're suggesting, also -- but I tend to steer away from putting javascript in as concantenated strings from the server and try to just give JS what it needs so it can run organically.   What you're writing *should* work.

Comment: Sorry, i'm still new to javascript. so I did the div, and the getElementById. how do I insert it into the maps? I tried var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(" & latitude & ", " & longitude & ");  Thanks

Comment: something like  `var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("my_lat_div_id"), document.getElementById("my_long_div_id"));`    assuming you have two DIVs written out like `<div id='my_lat_div_id'>lat_number_here</div>` and `<div id='my_long_div_id'>long number here</div>`

Comment: Hi Jason, doing that gave me a blank map. If I did document.getElementById('latitude').getAttribute('value'), a map comes up but it points to McGrath Holden Liverpool istead of my location. just below Nigeria in the sea.

Comment: Found the problem. it needed innerHTML instead. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to write it in:

```
<% Response.Write("..
   ..
   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(" & latitude & ", " & longitude & ");
   ..
")%>
```

Comment: Hi, i'm getting the error BC30648: String constants must end with a double quote. I'm sure I closed it with a double quote at the back. Any other ideas? Thanks